# Any Original Xbox games I can play on the Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox

So I sadly do not own an original Xbox, but I want to play original Xbox games on my Xbox 360. So I believe some Original Xbox games are available on Xbox 360. Does anyone have any original Xbox game ideas that are good for the Xbox 360?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full list of original Xbox games which are backwards-compatible on the Xbox 360 can be found on Wikipedia at [List of Xbox games compatible with Xbox 360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_games_compatible_with_Xbox_360).

Comment: Usually, when posting a link to the answer, we take whatever is of use in said link and paste it in our answers. That has for effect that if the link dies, like the site is taken offline or just the URL changes, then your answer is still good because the info is here too.

Comment: @Fredy31 I think that's a reasonable rule in most cases, but this list is hundreds of items long. It's not practical to paste that in this specific answer

Comment: Using the Code block might make it not so long (it creates a block where its like 300px high, and then scrolls through.)